# entitymanager persist doesn't save anything and no error throwed

Tags: entitymanager, persist

I have a problem with my jpa (eclipselink) when I call entitymanager to persist or to merge an object. It does'nt insert any row in database and it deosn't throw any error. but if I call entitymanager to find or executequery i get good results. so I think its a problem of the transaction.

```
**My entity:

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5088872371835299410L; 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String nom;

    public Person() {}
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

**My dao:

@Repository
public class PersistenceDao implements IPersistenceDao{
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    private EntityManager session;
    private EntityTransaction trx;

     private EntityManager getSession(){
        if(null == emf) 
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Spring07");
        session = emf.createEntityManager();
        return session;
    }

    public EntityTransaction getTrx(){
        if(null == trx || !trx.isActive())
            trx = this.session.getTransaction();
        return trx;
    }

    public void beginTransaction(){
        this.trx.begin();
    }

    public void commit(){
        this.trx.commit();
    }

    public void flush(){ 
        this.session.flush();
    }

    public void rollBack(){ 
        if(null != trx && trx.isActive())
            this.trx.rollback();
    }
}

 *** My service

@Service
public class Service implements IService{
    @Autowired
    IPersistenceDao dao; 

    public Service(){}

    @Override
    public void add(Object obj) { 
        try { 
            dao.beginTransaction(); 
            dao.add(obj);
            dao.flush(); 
            dao.commit(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            dao.rollBack();
        } finally {
            dao.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object> listAll(Class clazz) {
        return dao.listALl(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public Object find(Class clazz, Object id) {
         return dao.find(clazz, id);
    }

    public Object update(Object obj) {
           Object o = null;
           try {
                logger.info(" Begin transaction");
                dao.beginTransaction();
                logger.info(" persisting obj into db");
                o = dao.update(obj);
                logger.info(" commit");
                dao.commit();  
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                dao.rollBack();
            }  
           return o;
        }
}

*** My applicationConext.xml
  contains just:
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>
this package contains two subpackages dao and service who contains my dao and my service

**** My class Main
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
        IService iservice = (Service) context.getBean("Service");
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setNom("jean");

        iservice.add(p);
}
}

**** My persistence is correct.
because if I do:
Person p = new Person();
p.setNom("rchxxx"); 

 Person p = new Person();
  p.setNom("jean");
EntityManager manager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Spring07").createEntityManager();

        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(p);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();
```

it inserts a row in database but if use spring it doesn't.
i used @transactional, flush, ... always the same problem no rw inserted and no error throwed.
Any help please.

Comment: I don't see the annotation defining which table the Person object is mapping to. Could that be the problem?

Comment: thx for answering. the table is  created by eclipselink its name by default is the same as the entity with the fisrt char in lowercase in my case its name is person. i don't think that is the problem because i retreive (using find or executeQuery().getresultlist) data without any problem. the probelm is when i want to persist or to merge data. thanx

Comment: i need help please ?